# How do I transfer all files and subdirectories in a folder via FTP in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ftp

Running SQL Server 2008, in SSIS appending an `*` to the folder path got all the loose files, but doesn't move the subdirectories.  I could set up a ftp create directory task and a ftp transfer task for each of the subdirectories, but I was looking for a less tedious, more robust, way to handle this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had three subdirectories so I bit the bullet and just did the 3 creates and moves for their files, seemed less a hassle than adding a new program into the mix.  Although I would certainly consider that if I had a bigger job to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can always rely on a command-line ftp client that you know that can handle the whole operation on a single step (e.g. winscp).

Then you call it via the execute process task component.